# AWS Lambda | How to rollback database changes due to execution timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

My team is working on an AWS Lambda function that has a configured timeout of 30 seconds. Given that lambdas have this timeout constraint and the fact that they can be reused for subsequent requests, it seems like there will always be the potential for the function's execution to timeout prior to completing all of its necessary steps. Is this a correct assumption? If so, how do we bake in resiliency so that db updates can be rolled back in the case of a timeout occurring after records have been updated, but a response hasn't been returned to the function's caller?

To be more specific, my team is managing a Javascript-based lambda (Node.js 16.x) that sits behind an Api Gateway and is an implementation of a REST method to retrieve and update job records. The method works by retrieving records from DynamodDB given certain conditions, updates their states, then returns the updated job records to the caller. Is there a means to detect when a timeout has occurred and to rollback (either manually or automatically) the updated db records so that they're in the same state as when the lambda began execution?

Comment: This statement indicates you are confused how Lambda works: "Given that lambdas have this timeout constraint and the fact that they can be reused for subsequent requests, it seems like there will always be the potential for the function's execution to timeout prior to completing all of its necessary steps." Each execution gets 30 seconds. It doesn't matter if it's being reused, each time it is reused the 30 seconds starts over.

Comment: Ahhh I see, thanks for that clarification. I guess my question still stands though, if the process took longer than expected, is there a means to detect timeouts and rollback db changes?

Comment: What you are describing is what Database transactions were meant to solve. To do what you want you would have to do all the DynamoDB updates in the function in a single DynamoDB transaction.

Comment: Yes, but we have additional functionality that occurs after the core logic of our lambda, eg. logging cleanup. In the event that the ancillary code was the result of the execution taking longer than normal, would there be a way to detect that the lambda is or is about to timeout, then execute some rollback procedures, most likely manually given that the core db transaction had completed, in response?

Comment: If the Lambda is about to time out, it probably doesn't have enough time to connect back to DynamoDB and perform a rollback of everything it has done. In that type of scenario I don't think there is a solution to do exactly what you want. If you are really worried about this, why not increase the function's timeout?

Comment: **_WHY_ have you configured a timeout of 30 seconds?** Lambda functions can run for up to 15 minutes. An API Gateway request will timeout after 29 seconds, so there is no benefit in taking 30+ seconds to respond to a request. However, the Lambda function could certainly run for longer if you wish to do additional operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important to consider the consequences of what you are trying to do here. Instead of finding ways to detect when your Lambda function is about to expire, the best practice is to first monitor a good chunk of executed requests and analyze how much time, on average, it takes to complete the said requests. Perhaps 30 seconds may not be enough to complete the transaction implemented as a Lambda function.

Once you work with an admittable timeout that suits the average execution time for requests, you can minimize the possibility of rollbacks because of incomplete executions with the [support for transactions in DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-apis.html). It allows you to group multiple operations together and submit them as a single all-or-nothing, thus ensuring atomicity.

Another aspect related to the design of your implementation is about how fast can you retrieve data from DynamoDB without compromising the timeout. Currently, your code retrieves records from DynamoDB and then updates them if certain conditions are met. This creates a need for this read to happen as fast as possible so the subsequent operation of update can start. A way for you to speed up this read is [enabling the DAX (DynamoDB Accelerator)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.html) to achieve in-memory acceleration. This acts as a cache for DynamoDB with microseconds of latency.

Finally, if you wat to be extra careful and not even start a transaction in DynamoDB because there will be not enough time to do so, you can use the context object from the Lambda API to query for the remaining time of the function. In **Node.js**, you can do this like this:

```
let remainingTimeInMillis = context.getRemainingTimeInMillis()
if (remainingTimeInMillis < TIMEOUT_PASSED_AS_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE) {
   // Cancel the execution and clean things up
}
```

Comment: All good suggestions, I'll take this back to my team and review to see what makes the most sense. Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm glad you have found this useful. Let us know if we can help any further.